# Find $ \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^3 +1} dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Find $ \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^3 +1} dx$

What cantor should I choose?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What's a cantor?

Comment: Georg Cantor should work.

Comment: contour?${}{}{}$

Comment: I was trying to use the complex analysis to integrate it. But I could not choose the good $C_R$ line of integration.

Comment: You don't need complex analysis for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^3+1}dx$ =?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782531/int-0-infty-fracxx31dx). Here is a solution with complex analysis: [integration using residue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610172/integration-using-residue). Please use Approach0 to search for duplicates.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Contour integration isn't the best approach. It's better to take $x=\tan^{2/3}t$, so the integral is$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac23\tan^{1/3}tdt=\frac{\pi}{3}\csc\frac{2\pi}{3}=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: I can not understand how did you integrated the last part?

Comment: @MathGin Using $2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2a-1}t\cos^{2b-1}tdt=\operatorname{B}(a,\,b)=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$, together with $\Gamma(a)\Gamma(1-a)=\pi\csc\pi a$.